# UI-Router $stateParams Not Returning Values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular 1.6.9, UI-Router 1.0.15

The objective is the use the resolver to return the values for binding into Angular components. I have two third-party examples that work, one the tutorial Hello Galaxy example at the UI Router site and another a simple case in Codepen.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XdKQmifZ69pcYeBnQ945?p=preview

See the Pen [Angular JS UI-Router State Params](https://codepen.io/StretchKids/pen/wmxmjR/) by David ([@StretchKids](https://codepen.io/StretchKids)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

However, no matter how I cut and paste, I haven't been able to get the resolver function in my Codepen Project to see the passed object. The object config is in the fred.js and ethel.js under components. The button passing the object is in the index.pug file (Codepen also makes the index.html available).

The program goes to the state and executes the resolver function. However both $stateParameters and $transition$.params() are empty. Ugh!

The snippet does not execute.

```js
   .module("MyApp")
   .component("fred", {
      templateUrl: "components/fred.html",
      bindings: { name: "@" },
      controller: function($stateParams){
         var vm = this;
         vm.activeId = $stateParams.id;
       vm.resolveId = this.name;
      }
   })
   .config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state({
         name: "fred",
         url: "/fred",
         component: "fred",
         resolve: {
            name: function($transition$, $stateParams) {
               ;
               return $stateParams.id;
            }
         }
```

```html
md-button(ng-repeat="name in ac.lvl1" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="{{name}}({id: 'bar'})") {{name}}
```

This is a link to the CodePen project: https://codepen.io/StretchKids/project/editor/AJPvQm#

HELP!!!

Thanks,

David

Comment: This is the UI-Router Hello Galaxy project in Codepen. It Works...mine doesn't. Ugh!

https://codepen.io/StretchKids/project/editor/AxbrBw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching and testing, I found the answer. First I broke the UI-Router *Hello Galaxy* example. Searching said passed parameters had to included in the URL.

That explained why the *Hello Galaxy* example passed the id of the person and then searched the people array of person objects rather than just passing the person object which it already had. Definitely the long way around the barn!

What was needed was the addition of a params object in the state definition to declare the $stateParams variables in advance.

```js
{
         name: "person",
         url: "/{person.id}",
         component: "person",
         params:{data:null},
         resolve: {
            person: function($stateParams,$transition$) {
               return $stateParams.data.person;
            }
         }
      }
```

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/states#state-properties

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.14/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#params

http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters

This may be the best of the group: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component